# Related Rates Triangle Problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Part of a homework problem I have for my Calc class. 
In a right triangle with base = 10, height = h, and the angle across from the hight = theta, theta is increasing at a rate of 15/26 rad/min

At what rate is the area of the triangle changing when h = 24.

1. 338/4
2. 39
3. 195/4
4. 182
5. 195

What I tried to do:

Area=(1/2)*(base)*(height)*sin(theta)

A=.5*10*24*sin(theta)

A=120*sin(theta)

(dA/dt)=120cos(theta)*(d(theta)/dt)

Then I did the inverse tangent of 24/10 to get the radians of theta when h=24. This means theta = 1.176 when h=24

Then I substituted in 1.176 for theta, 15/26 for (d(theta)/dt) and solved for (dA/dt)

I got (dA/dt)=26.63

What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area is just $\frac 12$base*height.  There should not be a factor $\sin \theta$  You need to write $h=$ some function of $\theta$, then take the derivative of the area with respect to $\theta$ You can calculate $\theta$ from the fact that $h=24$.  Then you are given $\frac {d\theta}{dt}$

Comment: Am I right in thinking that h = 10*tan(theta)  ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct